# A few minutes of CPU time but on 1500 servers - where?

Tags: hosting

I have developed a software concept where I need to have approximately 1500 servers respond in parallel, in order to have a user interface that is responsive enough. I tried it out on a $1/month webhotel, and it could do my calculations and return the result via internet to me in 15ms, if preloaded by a previous request. That webhotel would actually solve the problem, if I could get 1500 accounts distributed on 1500 different servers, but they don't have that many servers.

Where can I get an online service, where I can run up to 30 minutes of CPU-time native code (or .net, java or similar), distributed on 1500 servers, in a responsive way? It would be nice if it costs significantly less than $2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good experience with the Rackspace Cloud. Each instance is a few cents an hour, and there is an API available.

[Rackspace Cloud Servers](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers)

*Edit: fixed underscores in link*

Comment: How do I get 1500 separate computers with rackspacecloud?

Comment: @Lars Go to that link; you can either provision the VPSes manually or using their open-source cloud API.  Amazon and Rackspace are the two big guys in this space at the moment; IMO Rackspace has the edge for the time being, with better API support, plus I like their portal better.

Answer (score 3):

An hour of an EC2 small instance costs $0.085; 1500 of those is only $127.50.  Sounds like it's exactly what you want.

Comment: How much latency can be expected in EC2?

Comment: I believe EC2 has a limitation in the number of servers you can spin up without talking to Amazon.

Comment: @phoebus: So talk to Amazon then.  @Lars: Their network's pretty solid.

Comment: @womble: Solidity is good, but how much latency? Are we talking <1ms, 10ms, 100ms, 1000ms?

Comment: What sort of latency are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

EC2 should accommodate but you will need to [speak to Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2) in advance.

Latency between instances isn't guaranteed and will vary. [This article](http://tech.mangot.com/roller/dave/entry/ec2_variability_the_numbers_revealed) provides some useful information about what to expect.